# How to set title to a div in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code, but it`s giving me errors

```
 <div id="ChangePassword" title="Change password for "&<%=item.Name%>>
        <%Html.RenderPartial("PasswordDetails", Model); %>
    </div>
```

I need to display the name in the title. How can I do that?

---

I actually want to dipslay the name of the employee in the div when the link is clicked.  How can I do that?

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.employee) { %>

    <tr>
        <td><%=item.Name %></td>
        <td><%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { userID = item.ID })%></td>
        <td><a href="#" id="password_link" >Change Password</a></td>
        <td> <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { Class = "deleteLink", title = item.Name })%></td>           
   </tr>

<% } %>

  $("#password_link").click(function() {
        $('#ChangePassword').dialog('open');
        return false;

        });


<div id="ChangePassword" title="Change password for <%=item.Name%>"> 
<%Html.RenderPartial("PasswordDetails", Model); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="ChangePassword" title="Change password for <%=item.Name%>">
    <%Html.RenderPartial("PasswordDetails", Model); %>
</div>
```

You didn't have the actual name in the title tag, your quotes ended too early.

---

To display the name in the div, I'd do the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#ChangePassword').attr('title', '<%= item.Name %>');
    $('#ChangePassword').dialog('open');return false;" 
    id="password_link" >Change Password</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Going further, I need to display the title of a dialog box as shown above using the div title.  Is there a better option?

Comment: Thanks, but the title isn`t being displayed, though the dialog box is being opened.

Comment: It seems that the attribute isn`t working.  I have it some other way, but the attribute to set the title isn`t working.

Comment: The title attribute of a div is only displayed when you hover your mouse over it. To get what you're looking for, place a span tag at the top of that div, and fill it in the same space I filled the title with the item.Name.

Comment: You mean I shouldn`t be using the div and instead use a span to show the dialog?

Comment: No, you can still use the div, but have a span inside it to show the name. And you set the html of the span to the name.

Comment: I have not understood. could you please give me an example.  Why do I need a span when the dialog is on the div?

Comment: You're right, you don't need it. The dialog func takes the title from the title of your div. I've just tested my code and it seems to work. Do you get a javascript exception?

Comment: I don`t have an exception, rather the partial view is being displayed when the page is loaded!